# Parse variable value to imagefill color in php

Tags: php, forms, image, creation, imagejpeg

im creating a image generator with php and i have a problem.

I have a form that asks for color that's already defined

```
    <select name="background color">
                        <option value=" 255, 0, 0">Red</option>
                        <option value="0,128,0">Green</option>
                        </select>
```

Once i select it and do my thing it gets stored in a variable with the POST method

```
?php

$height=$_POST['height'];
$width=$_POST['width'];
$cbackground=$_POST['backgroundcolor'];
$ctext=$_POST['text color'];
$text=$_POST['text'];
$arr = get_defined_vars();

header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagefill($img, 0, 0, 255, 545, 543);
```

as you can see in the last line i hard coded a color, but what i want to acomplish is to call the value from the cbackground variable like this
or similar.

```
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $cbackground);
```

when i do this i only get a little grey square, so it doesnt work as intended.

There is any way to make it work? properly?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can use is use the value part of :

```
   <select name="backgroundcolor">
      <option value=" 255, 0, 0">Red</option>
      <option value="0,128,0">Green</option>
   </select>
```

And explode the string to get an array with the 3 numbers :

```
$valueArray = explode(",",str_replace(" ","",$_POST['backgroundcolor']));
```

Now you have an array made of :

```
  [0] => 255, 
  [1] => 0, 
  [2] => 0
```

So you just have to use it like so :

```
imagefill($img, 0, 0, $valueArray[0], $valueArray[1], $valueArray[2]);
```